# Система репортов Discord.py

Tags: python, discord, бот, discord.py

Я пытаюсь сделать систему репортов, работает команда как /report сообщение , и далее данное сообщение должно прийти в определенный канал , но не приходит , я не могу понять в чем проблема и почему не работает, смотрел статьи как сделать так чтобы сообщение отправлялось в отдельный канал , но перепробовав несколько способов понял что ни один из них мне не помог.

```
@commands.command()
async def report(self,ctx):
    channel = bot.get_channel(int(1063486475620065282))
    repmessage = ctx.message.content
    await ctx.send(embed = discord.Embed(
        description = 
        f"**[REPORT]**" + '\n' +
        f"----------------------------------------------" + '\n' +
        f"**Репорт был успешно отправлен.**" + '\n' +
        "----------------------------------------------"))
    await channel.send(embed = discord.Embed(
        description = 
        f"**[REPORT]**" + '\n' +
        f"----------------------------------------------" + '\n' +
        f"Nick: {ctx.author}" + '\n' +
        f"ID: {ctx.author.id}" + '\n' +
        f"Сообщение: {repmessage[7:]}" + '\n' + 
        "----------------------------------------------"))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы не прикрепили ошибку. Значит будем гадать.

Во-первых, вы принимаете сообщение репорта с помощью `{repmessage[7:]}` это выглядит просто ужасно. Вы можете принимать сообщение репорта отдельным аргументом, например `repmess`:

```
@commands.command()
async def report(self, ctx, *, repmess):
```

И уже отправить сообщение:

```
    await channel.send(embed = discord.Embed(
        description = 
        f"**[REPORT]**" + '\n' +
        f"----------------------------------------------" + '\n' +
        f"Nick: {ctx.author}" + '\n' +
        f"ID: {ctx.author.id}" + '\n' +
        f"Сообщение: {repmess}" + '\n' + 
        "----------------------------------------------"))
```

Во-вторых, Вам не нужно использовать `int` в `bot.get_channel`:

```
    channel = bot.get_channel(1063486475620065282)
```

Так как это коги, ошибка скорее всего возникает из-за того что вы используете `bot.get_channel`, попробуйте:

```
    channel = self.bot.get_channel(1063486475620065282)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Если не помогло - напишите мне ошибку, чтобы я понимал в чём дело.

Comment: Не помогло. Ошибка: в строке await channel.send(embed = discord.Embed(. Ошибка: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send'

Comment: Вы убрали `int` в строке `bot.get_channel(int(1063486475620065282))`? И попробовали `self.bot.get_channel`?

Comment: Да, я так и сделал.

Comment: это странно. у меня всё работает.

Comment: Я предоставил скриншот. Изменив только те ошибки которые я Вам указал - бот отвечает и отправляет сообщение. Я думаю, что проблема не в команде, а в вашем ID канала. Проверьте его.

Comment: Кстати говоря о вашей ошибке. В ней как раз и говорится о том, что Вы не получаете канал который хотите. Удостоверьтесь что бот есть в гильдии в которую вы хотите отправить сообщение.

Comment: Сейчас пойду перепроверю , спасибо за помощь

Comment: Все равно ошибка. await channel.send(embed = discord.Embed(
                                               
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send'. Хотя я и ставил id других каналов.

Comment: Я смог починить , я просто код вставил в main файл , убрал self и сделал через bot.command , после чего заработало , с одной стороны это хорошо , но с другой вопроc. Почему не работает в когах?

Comment: Даже не знаю. Сейчас попробую протестировать его в когах.

Comment: Проверил - всё отлично работает даже в когах. Скорее всего что-то с Вашими когами)

Comment: Понял, спасибо, буду разбираться